# FPC Connector type for Echo Dot 2nd gen

Tags: fpc

currently i'm trying to interface Alexa LED/Microphone board with Raspberry pi. The big Alexa (1 Gen) has a 0.5mm pitch - I got an 0.1" adapter for this and it's working. Now I'd like to do the same with the Echo Dot, but the Dot has an alternating pitch. Can anyone suggest any kind of adapter for this FPC cable? The width of the whole thing is 11.4mm - nothing I could do by hand... :-)

[image]

Alternate source for image: https://de.ifixit.com/Anleitung/Amazon+Echo+Dot+2.+Generation+Flachbandkabel+austauschen/100828#s188942

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's a dual-row style FPC - essentially there are two rows of alternating contacts in the connector allowing for a tighter pitch on the ribbon cable.

Based on your measurements the pitch comes in at approximately 0.3mm, and I count 37 contacts.

Something along the lines of the Molex 504740 series such as [5047403700](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/5047403700_FFC_FPC_CONNECTORS.xml) which is a 37-pin dual row 0.3mm pitch connector.

To ensure compatibility, you'd need to also check that the depth difference between the contacts matches the FPC, along with the thickness of the kapton material.

Comment: i measured again - the width is more like 11.5mm. Thickness of the cable is 0.25mm. I used my phone camera as "microscope" and measured the broader contacts again - your 0.3mm assumption is correct. But I guess your linked Molex (thanks for that anyway!) is just the connector and no PCB, right?

Comment: @darkspirit510 Shopping questions are off-topic on EE.SE, but part identification is on-topic. I've identified the part or type of part, its up to you to find the breakout board you need if one is available from anywhere.